# PHP: Login does not redirect

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, header

Okay so basically, i have been trying this for and hour or 2 now.
When a user log's in on my webpage, they dont seem to be redirected to the user.php.
They only see a small empty box and are still on index.php.

My form action is this:

```
 <form id="login" method="POST" autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

And then there is the code to be executed when the user successfully log's in:

```
if ($username == $dbusername && md5($password) == $dbpassword)
{                  
  //You're in!
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

  header("Location:user.php");      
}
else die blablabla
```

And still the users dont seem to be redirected.

What would i do?

Comment: make sure you don't output anything before calling `header`. also look around for why (plain) md5 is bad

Comment: try placing `exit;` after `header()` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is sensitive to XSS, so please escape it.

Put a die() statement after your header statement (which should use only absolute URIs, not relative ones like you did).

Answer (score 0):

try changing to this...

```
if ($username == $dbusername && md5($password) == $dbpassword)
{                  
   //You're in!
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

     header('Location:/user.php');   
     exit();
 }
  else die blablabla
```

Also always use exit(); after a header redirect

Comment: That didn't work either. But thx anyways. This is getting frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

If the header tag is not working for you, maybe you could try html meta alternative (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_meta.asp) with zero wait time. And if you use this method, dont forget to place link to the page you are redirecting, if the redirection doesnt happen.

Comment: Thank you, i will remember that if the header tags is not working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different browsers? I've heard Chrome needs
    header("Status: 200");

Avoid using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] (security risk) and use SHA256 instead of MD5 (also look into salts).

Have you tried checking if the "if condition" are actually met?
Also try using a complete url in your header and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Okay, i now have added the SHA256 and will take a look into salts. Thx!